# How does a IP packet from a remote server "find" a home computer behind a NAT firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, home-networking, nat

I understand communication between a remote machine, e.g. a webserver and users home computer/device can only occur if the users computer initiates the communication (assuming your firewall/network is properly configured).

And that

- a typical home network consists of many devices with uniquely issued IP addresses e.g. `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2` etc
- That same network connects to the internet via a single "public" IP address

What I'm curious to know is, when the remote server sends a response to the home computer's request, how are the response packets able to uniquely identify the users computer when - *and Im making an assumption that could be wrong here* - that the remote server is only able to "see" the overall networks public IP address?

Comment: That is what NAT does. TCP is a connection orriented protocol, so when you on the inside negotiate a connection to an external server, the firewall remembers that you started the connection. returning packets will have the right port number, and SYN, and ACK values for that specific connection within them, so the router knows that the packet is part the connection it observed previously, and pass the packet into the LAN and to the host that started the connection. as you said, the external server only knows the connection, including your public IP, port number and SYN/ACK values.

Comment: thanks, so the local firewall remembers your connection and waits for packets containing the correct SYN/ACK values. I understood SYN/ACK occurred on the *"three way handshake"*. once the handshake has occurred, do these SYN/ACK values continue to exist within all packets?

Comment: yes, and they change (predictably) with each packet, so that TCP can tell whether or not its gotten all the packets, or if its missed a few and needs to ask for a resend of a particular one. be careful not to confuse syn/ack values with syn/ack flags. the flags are turned on or off during the handshake, but the values start at a random value and increase from there with each packet successfully sent. Note that these values are predictable only within the connection. if someone on the outside was observing and syn vals were too easy to predict, they could hijack the connection.

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure  Note that not only are there syn/ack flag bits in the 110th and 111th bits, there are also 32-bit fields for holding the syn and ack values. On the very first packet, ACK is off, and there is no value, but every other packet will have one, and they increment with every reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address is not the only thing that the remote server sees.  It also sees a *port*.  The port is a 16-bit integer.

Think of a computer as an apartment building.  The IP is like the street address.  The port identifies which apartment.  Thus, a browser, a mail client, and so on, all run on the one IP belonging to the computer but each is given, by the OS, one or more unique ports to use.

When a local computer sends a packet to a remote server, the packet is sent from a port on the local computer to a port on the remote server.  The firewall receives that packet and sends it on to the remote server but it does so only after changing the *from* IP address to local network's public IP and also likely changing the *from* port to some other port of the firewall's choosing.

When the public server responds, it sends a packet back to the  the public IP and the port number that it was given.  The firewall receives that packet and sends it on to whichever computer initiated the connection on that port.

If the firewall receives a packet directed to a port that no local computer was using, it is the firewall's job to keep that packet out of the local network. It can silently drop it or it can noisily send a reject message back to the source.

#### Some common port numbers

When your browser sends a request to some remote server, that request very likely goes to the remote server's port 80.

- 22 = ssh
- 25 = smtp (mail)
- 53 = DNS (domain name server)
- 80 = http
- 194 = IRC
- 220 = IMAP
- 993 = POP (mail)

Typically, low number ports, up to 1024, are reserved for use by the operating system.  High numbered ports, maybe 32000 to 65535, are used by user applications, like browsers.

Comment: its important to note that the NAT firewall will not allow just any packet from the external server back in. the packet must be part of the same connection, going to the same port on the LAN client, or in the case of a connection-less protocol like UDP, must come in within a very narrow time-frame. otherwise there would be many plausible attacks against NAT routers using common ports like 1024, since most clients use 1024 as the port of their first connection, and is thus almost always in a state where it could receive a packet if NAT let it, even if its unsolicited.

Comment: thanks, for both fantastic answers - So when the local firewall rewrites the port as the local packets are sent, it instructs remote server send the request back to `port x`. does it use a very uncommon port, say `port#33789` as a way of identifying the server response, kind of like, *"ah , I m getting a packet on `port#33789` that must be from xyz_server "*?

Comment: well, remember, unless you are using port forwarding, the port is only part of the equation, since the reply must be part of the established connection. As for port numbers, windows clients assign the first open port above 1024 when initiating a connection to the outside. Server ports are more difficult to predict. some services can maintain differant individual connections over the same port, but others use portmapping to map each clients connection to another free port, and only listen for NEW connections on their well known port number (for instance TCP\80).

Comment: @MichaelColeman Yes, the firewall keeps a translation table to associate the port used on the internet side with a computer and port on the LAN side.