# How does a NAT differentiate between the receivers(behind it) of a packet stream?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, connection, nat

After reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/880223/how-does-a-ip-packet-from-a-remote-server-find-a-home-computer-behind-a-nat-fi) question, I still don't understand how packets are being mapped to the their corresponding hosts(receivers) behind the NAT in the case of connectionless protocols.

The accepted answer suggests that the NAT keeps a record of the host's port number, SYN and ACK values in order to correctly map the incoming stream to it. However, in the case of connectionless protocols the SYN and ACK values are not used thus only the port number remains a means of identifying packets. Is it sufficient? If more hosts behind that NAT use the same source port(a likely case with large subnets(i.e. 192.xx.xx.xx)) are the incoming packets broadcasted to all hosts that have used the respective port in their packets?

Comment: The posted answer is correct. It holds for UDP.  For large subnets (10.x.x.x - Class A) you would probably find that the use network uses more than one router.  The limiting factor would be the number of connections and handling them well, not exhausting the NAT table. A 192.168.x.x network is Class C of up to 253 Hosts.

Comment: @albal youi must've been told by now that classes aren't used anymore, so it's misleading to use the term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/880228/269989) to the question you linked to-

> The firewall receives that packet and sends it on to the remote server but it does so only after changing the from IP address to local network's public IP and **also likely changing the from port to some other port of the firewall's choosing.**

If two machines behind the NAT send connectionless (UDP) packets to the same server, the NAT will forward them from different ports on the NAT.  Then the "to" port on the packets from the server will let the NAT determine what machine to forward those packets to.

**Edit:** For example, with clients A and B behind the NAT and server S on the Internet, UDP transmissions might look like this (machine:port):

```
A:31337 -> NAT:7 (ECHO) // NAT:31338 -> S:7
B:31337 -> NAT:7 (ECHO) // NAT:**31339** -> S:7
S:7 -> NAT:31338 // NAT:7 -> A:31337
S:7 -> NAT:**31339** // NAT:7 -> B:31337
```

Both A and B are using source port 31337, but the NAT maps them to different ports (31338 and 31339, respectively) from the NAT out to server S.

Comment: What if both machines are using the same source ports. How does the NAT do the mapping between packets?

Comment: @Sebi added example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but

If  you have 2 machines behind NAT, and two  machines with public IPs outside NAT. Then the machines behind NAT could know one remote machine from the other, because the remote machines have different IP addresses.  And the remote ones know one host behind NAT, from another host behind NAT, because they access the dest port of the one they want to send to.    If the two remote machines were also behind NAT, and wanted to send to whichever machines on the other side, that are also behind NAT.. then IP and port wouldn't give away who the sender was.